# C# File/Directory Permissions for local share

Tags: c#, permissions, acl, sharefile, directory-security

I need a file to be editable by all local users. The application saves common information to all users in its own folder under ProgramData. I need to guarantee reading and writing to all users, it is so little information that it does not merit the use of a database.

I get the path to the folder from:`Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "InfoConfig");`

All users can read, write and create in this folder. **Except the files that are created by the other users**.

I already tried to remove Creator Owner without success. So my last attempt was not to inherit from the container folder and create the permissions from scratch for SYSTEM, Administrators and Users. But it didn't work either, here is my code.

```
            string sharedFolder = Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "InfoConfig");
        if (!Directory.Exists(sharedFolder))
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(sharedFolder);
            DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
            directorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);
            FileSystemRights fileSystemRights = 
                      FileSystemRights.FullControl | 
                      FileSystemRights.Modify | 
                      FileSystemRights.Read | 
                      FileSystemRights.Delete;
            SecurityIdentifier usersSid = 
                      new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
            SecurityIdentifier systemSid = 
                      new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null);
            SecurityIdentifier adminsSid = 
                      new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);

            FileSystemAccessRule rule = 
                      new FileSystemAccessRule(systemSid, fileSystemRights, AccessControlType.Allow);

            directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);

            rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminsSid, fileSystemRights, AccessControlType.Allow);
            directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);

            rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(usersSid, FileSystemRights.Read 
                     | FileSystemRights.Write 
                     | FileSystemRights.Modify, 
                     AccessControlType.Allow);
            directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);

            directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
        }
```

It still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hi Leonardo, can you confirm if the answer below helped out with your question, if yes, you can click the green tick to mark as resolved, it would benefits others who come across the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only considered the below snippet for `usersSid`, you can tweak it for the other *userTypes* as well

Have *added* `ObjectSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification, AccessRule, Boolean)` which *applies the specified modification to the Discretionary Access Control List (DACL) associated with this ObjectSecurity object (`directorySecurity` in our instance)*.

---

```
string sharedFolder = Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "InfoConfig");

 if (!Directory.Exists(sharedFolder))
 {
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(sharedFolder);
    DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

    directorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);

    FileSystemRights fileSystemRights = 
            FileSystemRights.FullControl | 
            FileSystemRights.Modify | 
            FileSystemRights.Read | 
            FileSystemRights.Delete;

    SecurityIdentifier usersSid = 
            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);


    FileSystemAccessRule rule =  new FileSystemAccessRule(usersSid, fileSystemRights,InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow);
    directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);

    bool result;
    directorySecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, rule, out result);

    if (!result)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to give full-control permission to all users for path " + path);
        }

    FileSystemAccessRule inheritedRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(
    usersSid,
    fileSystemRights,
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
    AccessControlType.Allow);

    bool inheritedResult;
    directorySecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, inheritedRule, out inheritedResult);

    if (!inheritedResult)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to give full-control permission inheritance to all users for " + path);
    }


    directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Can you suggest a link to understand how permissions work? Microsoft documentation is difficult to understand. Thank you!

Comment: I coudn't find any useful / easy-to-understand non microsoft reference. However, what I can suggest is you look up these two things to read, 1- Windows Access Control list which is returned by [Directory.GetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8#overloads)
2- [`FileSystemSecurity`] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity?view=netframework-4.8#methods)